# SharePoint Online(Modern experience): Follow sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, follow

I am working with SharePoint online.

Is there any option to add follow in Context Menu?

Is there any option to add it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Modern page experience, you can follow sites in SharePoint.

It will look like this:

[image]

Reference:

https://sharepointmaven.com/need-follow-sites-sharepoint/